# Forwarding authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In my ASP.NET application, I use a WebClient to download a file. This file is almost always on the company intranet, and requires permission to access. Whenever I run the application in VS, it works fine, because it is running in the context of my own permissions. However, when it is deployed to IIS, it runs in the context of "Network Service"'s permissions, which are basically non-existent (as you would expect) when it comes to the intranet.

I can see a few poor solutions here:

- Make an account specifically for the application, the details for which would be located in web.config and provided to the WebClient as strings. This is suboptimal, as not all users of the service have the same permissions.
- Require a username and password to be entered. This would never be approved, as the company uses certificates wherever possible. Passwords are used to log in to Windows, and almost everything past that point uses Windows authentication with the help of Kerberos

The optimal solution would be to pass the credentials of the current person accessing (and providing Windows authentication data via Kerberos) directly to the WebClient object. Is this possible? If so, how so? I would be so immensely grateful if someone could tell me, or at least put me out of my misery and tell me it cannot be done.

Comment: what type of file is this.. is it something that has sensitive data in it.. if not then I don't see why you would need to use Authentication .. do you use anything like SharePoint..?

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment as it's been a while since I've done ASP.NET, I'm sure someone else who is actively using it can provide better insight. That said, if I remember correctly, you want to enable impersonation. Which should run the web application with the credentials of user who is making the request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do this with WebClient, as everything with HTTP is going to be more transparent, ie. sending text in cookies/headers for authentication. WCF is however more geared for a windows intranet scenario, and you can easily access the windows identity from a property in addition to a lot of other impersonation options. I'm not saying re-write the whole thing with WCF, but it would be well suited for this particular scenario in my opinion.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292233/get-windows-username-from-wcf-server-side http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx

Comment: DJ - It has a great deal of sensitive data in it and is exclusive to high level executives. Yes, Sharepoint is used, but for a number of other reasons, this cannot run on the Sharepoint server. Mostly because this will not be used exclusively on the intranet.

JT - Thank you very much for putting me onto that. Had to make a couple of tweaks, but that worked.

Despertar - I would love nothing more. In fact, this was initially going to be running as a Windows 8 tablet app, but the Board almost exclusively uses iPads, so a web app is the new plan... Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impersonation turned out to be the optimum solution; thank you, JT.

There are plenty of good resources on tying Windows Authentication to impersonation. One that I didn't actually use, but have since discovered and which appears very comprehensive, is available here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication

Delegation was also required in my case, and this guy explains it fairly well, and links to a useful msdn document regarding it:

http://blog.reveille.org.uk/2010/01/asp-net-impersonation-delegation-2/