# Get Windows username via WCF Data Services (Silverlight)

Tags: windows, wcf

I'm trying get the windows username for my silverlight 4 application using WCF Data Services. I'm seeing the username when I'm debugging the application from my local machine. But when I'm running the application from web server, the username is coming out as null.
Please let me know if you need any other details. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is the method I'm using to get the username :**

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetWindowsUsername()
{
    string usr = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    return usr.ToString();
}
```

**Here is my Web.Config :**

```
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <!--<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>-->
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
      <!--<identity impersonate="false" />-->
    </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="OrderTrackingSystem.Web.OTSService.customBinding0"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                  <security>
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
            <service name="OrderTrackingSystem.Web.OTSService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OrderTrackingSystem.Web.OTSService.customBinding0"
                    name="OTSServiceCustom" contract="OrderTrackingSystem.Web.OTSService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**Here is my Service Config :**

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="OTSServiceCustom" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:49458/OTSService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="OTSServiceCustom" contract="OTSProxy.OTSService"
        name="OTSServiceCustom" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/292233/860243

Comment: That doesn't work for me because I'm not looking for authentication. I just need the windows username and I looked at the other post also. I'm getting the current as null.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a demo app to test things, the following worked for me..

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetWindowsUsername()
{
    string usr = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
    return usr;
}
```

But inorder to make this work you have to configure your binding as:

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="OTSServiceCustom">
           <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" />
           </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried it and it is asking for username and password in the web app. I tried it by disabling the anonymous access also in the authentication methods.

Comment: What authentication are you using for the web app? Asp Net forms authentication? You have to use NTLM for your web app as well, otherwise how do you know what windows user is logging in?

Comment: <authentication mode="Windows" />

Comment: You have to enable impersonation. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc(v=vs.100).aspx)