# Best way to get logged user identity c#

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity

I have a big system. This system consist of client desktop app and many wcf services. Each of wcf service have it's own logic and isolate it from client code. One of the services is authorization service. It's main task is to authenticate user and let all other services to know what user is logged on without additional stuff. For example, as i think i should at the start of client to make authentification of the user, check it's login and password and next generate some token and use this token in all requests to other services to let any service know what user is working with it. Well, firstly, i wanted to use claims authentification, but it is quite complicated for realization. Now an idea of my algorithm is to generete some kind of token, put it into the header of any request and pass to services. Service will send this token to the authorization service and service will check it.

The question is: is there any more beautiful and more easy for realization algorithm to let any service know which user is now working with him? Or maybe wcf have some standard solution for this problem?

**Update 1.** I can't use active directory and any windows default authorization mechanism. I have my own database of users, their roles and permissions. I need just to let other services to know the name of the user. I need to write this mechanism once and let other developers to use it in any wcf service of our system. Is it a bad idea to send a login in every request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Windows Username from WCF server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292233/get-windows-username-from-wcf-server-side)

Comment: No, it's a bit different because i'm not using windows identity. I have my own database of permissions and users and their roles.